# logic and set theory proof : $|A \cap B| <|A^C|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are sets then $|A \cap B| <|A^C|$.

I'm not sure how I should start this proof. Normally I would turn the proof into set theory notation, but I'm not sure if that works or if I an represent cardinality in set theory notation. If someone could show me how to get started that would be nice.

Comment: Take $A=B=\mathbb R$ with the underlying set $\mathbb R$. Then $|A^C|=|\emptyset|=0 < |\mathbb R| = |A \cap B|$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is not true in general, even for finite sets. A very simple counterexample is obtained by letting your universal set, $A$, and $B$ all be $\{0\}$: then $A\cap B=\{0\}$, so $|A\cap B|=1$, but $A^C=\varnothing$, so $|A^C|=0$. Clearly this idea can be extended to any non-empty universal set $U$: just take $A=B=U$, in which case $|A\cap B|=|U|>0$, while $|A^C|=|\varnothing|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your statement is true for $C=B$, but not in this case.
1) $B=\emptyset\implies |A\cap B|=0<1=|A^B|$
2) $|B|\geq1 \implies |A\cap B|\leq|A|<|A^{\{1\}}|\leq|A^B|$
Note that I used existence of empty function.